# Count the digits of a hexadecimal number and

Tags: c++, data-structures

So there is [L, R] range given and we have to count the number of integers  in the range such that

GCD(i, H(i)) H(i) represents sum of digits in hexadecimal representation.
H(27) = 1  + B = 1 + 11 = 12 , (27 is written as 1B in hexadecimal representation.)

I  have solved this question without making a prefix table, but when I am trying to make a prefix table it gives some unusual output.

I am attaching my code here.

**Input format**

The first line contains a positive integer denoting the number of questions that you are asked.
Each of the next lines contain two integers and denoting the range of questions.

**Output Format**

For each test case, you are required to print exactly numbers as the output.

Input:
3
1 3
5 8
7 12

Correct Output:
2
4
6

My Output(Incorrect):
1
2
4

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define fastIO ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL); cout.tie(NULL);
#define ll long long
const ll MOD  = 1000000007;


int pre[100001];
int sumdigit(int n)
{
    char hexadigit[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        int temp = n % 16;

        if (temp < 10)
        {
            hexadigit[i] = temp + 48;
            i++;
        }
        else

        {
            hexadigit[i] = temp + 55;
            i++;
        }
        n = n/16;
    }


    int sum  = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <  i; j++)
    {
        if (isdigit(hexadigit[j]))
            sum = sum + hexadigit[j] - '0';

        else
            sum = sum + hexadigit[j] - 'A' + 10;
    }
    return sum;

}

void  solve()
{
    int L, R;
    cin>>L>>R;

    cout << pre[R] - pre[L + 1]<<"\n";
}



int main()
{
// #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
//     freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
//     freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
// #endif

    pre[0] = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100001; i++)
    {
        if(__gcd(i, sumdigit(i) ) > 1)
            count++;
        else
            pre[i] = count  +  pre[i - 1];
    }


    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        solve();
    }
}
```

Comment: What unusual output do you get? For what input?

Comment: Output in my case 
 1
 2
 4

Comment: Add that information to the question itself, not as a comment.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - Please don't *ever* do that. See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)

Comment: Perhaps show what the correct version without the `pre` looks like.